# Is there a way to build asset bundle that exclude texture2d from an image?

Tags: unity

In unity 4.x, I can archive this because I can select my resource type directly as Sprite variable before putting it into the bundle via BuildAssetBundle. However, in Unity 5.x, I need to put the name in the Editor can I cannot choose my resource type as Sprite only in the Editor. When I make the bundle, bundle will have both Texture2D and Sprite which I only want Sprite to save the memory and disk space. The bundle will exclude Texture2D only if I create the bundle from Prefab not the image itself but I want only the raw image. What should I do?